# Minimize database interactions with caching

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, caching

I was looking at this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

It's an amazing way of caching stuff, but it happens on the database side, it would be great if there was some kind of code for PHP that would do the same for you.

I mean you would send your queries to that intermediary layer, it would look at your queries, decides if it needs to connect to the db again or not.

Has anyone made anything like that for PHP? Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: Most people would use [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

Comment: there are multiple php caching scripts.

Comment: Ideally, scripts should connect to the database once, execute as many queries that the page requires, then close the connection for each page served, so you wouldn't need to connect all the time. You might want to consider [`mysql_pconnect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php), although I wouldn't use it personally.

Comment: IIRC the MySQL native PHP driver supports PHP client side caching.

Answer (score 0):

For any caching it is important that the actual caching and invalidation are done by the same application (e.g. the sql-server).
While it probably isn't difficult to write some client-side query-cache this does absolutely make no sense in most cases as the client-cache would not be notified (by the sql-server) when the cached data becomes outdated. But actually the query-cache is that layer you suggest.
As mysql's query-cache doesn't know anything about your application-logic, it has to invalidate the cache by other criteria (e.g. the table changed). This can result in poor performance if used as the only cache (especially on fast-changing tables).
Therefore you should use some sophisticated caching engine on your client with respect to your application logik.